# UItableViewCell not dequeing properly ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

Using `UITableView` and found that `cells` are not dequeuing properly.
Here is the code which i have written.I have read that, have to override `prepareForReuse`, but how to use that method, not getting. Please help me out.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
    textLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyUnderwood" size:16];
    textLabel.text = [_tableLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;


}
```

Here is the image of `UITableView` which i am getting when i scroll the `TableView`[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like a dequeue/reuse problem, just a formatting problem.  By the way, as someone from the Southern Hemisphere, let me point out that it is "Australia" and "New Zealand"

Comment: So according to you , How to solve this issue?

Comment: Looking again, where is `cell` defined?  I would expect to see `UITableViewCell *cell` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Is `cell` an iVar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will fix your issue, but this code uses a local `UICell *` variable, uses `self.tableLabelArray` rather than accessing the property iVar directly and uses the textLabel property rather than searching by tag.

My suspicion is that your `cell` variable is an iVar, not a local so that may be causing you problems, and therefore this may help, but it could also be that you need a font size smaller than 16, so I have specified `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
  UITableViewCell *returnCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (returnCell==nil) {
    returnCell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
 returnCell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyUnderwood" size:16];
 returnCell.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
 returnCell.text = [self.tableLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 return returnCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = [_tableLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyUnderwood" size:16];
return cell;

}
```

Comment: no its not working.Its not correct to alloc everytime